# Unity: Unable to take screenshots in server build

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to take snapshots in the server build of my Unity application.

But the output image is all grey. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071756/run-unity-standalone-in-headless-mode-whilst-capturing-screenshots), I read that in headless mode, calling `camera.Render()` is necessary for rendering. I changed my screenshot logic accordingly.

Here is my script

```
private IEnumerator TakeSnapshot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    var tempTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    camOV.targetTexture = tempTexture;
    camOV.Render();
    
    var tex = new Texture2D(tempTexture.width, tempTexture.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, tempTexture.width, tempTexture.height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = tempTexture;

    // Encode texture into PNG
    var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    snapshotBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    // File.WriteAllBytes("/Users/varun/Desktop/" + Time.time + ".png", bytes);
    Destroy(tex);  
}
```

I initalize the camera in the Start() method

```
    camOV = Camera.main;
```

This works fine inside the editor but once I create a server build for Mac and try to run it I get this error.

```
ReadPixels was called to read pixels from system frame buffer, while not inside drawing frame.
 #0 ???
 #1 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #2 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #3 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #4 operator delete[](void*, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #5  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.Texture2D:ReadPixelsImpl_Injected (UnityEngine.Texture2D,UnityEngine.Rect&,int,int,bool)
```

Can someone give any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: "From this post, I read that in headless mode, calling camera.Render() is necessary for rendering. " - OK, and where do you call camera.Render()? When is TakeSnapshot called/started?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I posted the incorrect code by mistake. Feel stupid. I've updated it with the correct code. Thanks!

Comment: @DMGregory Right now I am calling TakeSnapshot method a few seconds after the app is launched. Before calling it I populate some objects on the screen. I can see the snapshot png and it looks okay but only if I use the editor. If I use the server build I get the error.